# MySQL does not return any results anymore

Tags: php, mysql, string, search

My database is something like

```
id name age
1  john 21
2  mary 25
```

If I do something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name='john'
```

then it just returns 0 results. The strange thing is that it was working until one hour ago. This is XAMPP server where I'm working on my PHP program for several days now. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Returns 0 results in what context? Are you querying it from PHP, or is it not returning rows from the MySQL command line client either? If in  php, make sure you're checking `mysql_error()`

Comment: Put debugging statements in your script (for database connection, query, etc) and if the issue is not clear in those messages, add those messages to your question.

Comment: also check that the data has not changed underneath you.  also check you have not lost permissions to the table, or have not become a new user with different privileges.

Comment: I've tried everything from PHP to phpMyAdmin, and also a remote connection from another computer but nothing...
However if I enter something like:
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1
it returns one row!

Comment: No errors whatsoever neither on php nor on phpMyAdmin

Comment: Permissions are all set to administrator, I've been using root user

Comment: The most strange thing is that It was working, I was typing some code, and suddenly when I tried a query I was working on (a SELECT with a simple external variable) it just didn't respond as it used to...
Is there anything that can get full or a parameter that has been exceeded?... Something that fits this behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

Is it poss. a space exists around the name value?  Try changing the query from

```
name = 'john'
```

to

```
name like '%john%'.
```

If you can access the db, ensure there are no spaces in the column value.

Try a different value from your table, like mary, same thing?

If you're using php, try breaking and dumping the variable like

```
var_dump($name);
break;
```